# Compare two columns to return a third thats a date - Excel

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I want to compare two columns to return a third thats a date.

So I have one spreadsheet of raw data that has Column A= Photo ID, Column B=Number of beluga seen. In another tab have all the photo IDs and the dates the photos were taken. I want to match the photo IDs from the raw data to the spreadsheet that has the dates, so I can have the dates included with my raw data.

I've tried using

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(P2,$K$2:$K$7373,0)),"",VLOOKUP(P2,$K$2:$K$7373, 1, FALSE)) - Returns a blank cell 

=VLOOKUP(W2,$K$2:$K$7373,J:J,FALSE) - returns N/A

=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(P2,$K$2:$K$7373,0)),INDEX($J$2:$J$7373,MATCH(P2,$K$2:$K$7373,0)),0) - returns the same 01/01/1900 for every value.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Going to need some example data or an explanation of what your cell references are to be able to help.  Are any of these formula arrays?

Comment: So I have one spreadsheet of raw data that has Column A= Photo ID, Column B=Number of beluga seen. In another tab have all the photo IDs and the dates the photos were taken. I want to match the photo IDs from the raw data to the spreadsheet that has the dates, so I can have the dates included with my raw data.

Comment: Can you include sample data in the body of the post which would help us understand what each of the formulas are referencing?

Comment: What is the `lookupValue`(s), the `lookupRange`, and the `outputRange`?  Please edit your post to add the details up there to be very specific about your data, e.g., "i need to match number of beluga seen AND number of camels seen, then output the Photo ID."